# How can i pull out r/copypasta content and use it as a string?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I programmed a Discord-bot which replies to recieved dms with "bruh dming me has literally no point". A friend gave me this amazing idea to pull out the answers from r/copypasta. But i dont know how to do that so i asked. The important part of the code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.type === "dm" && message.author.id !== client.user.id) {
        console.log("-----DM-----")
        console.log(message.content)
        console.log(message.author.tag)
        console.log("-----DM-----")
        message.author.send("bruh dming me has literally no point");
        client.channels.cache.get('726919268142415973').send({
                embed: {
                color: 0x00baba,
                    author: {
                        name: "I recieved the following DM:",
                        icon_url: message.author.avatarURL
                    },
                    title: message.author.tag,
                    description: message.content,
                    timestamp: new Date(),
                    footer: {
                        icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
                        text: "Staff"
                    }
                }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to use the reddit API to pull content from a certain subreddit. Reddit's api is open to public, you COULD register your app and use their [official API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api)

Or you could use their open endpoints ! No need for credentials that way

1. Call `GET http://www.reddit.com/r/subreddit/new.json?sort=new`. (Change `sort=new` by any of those: rising, hot, top, new ...). This will return you a JSON of results, just parse the JSON and get the copypastas needed!
2. At the end of the JSON, there are 2 elements : `"after": "t3_hi5yy6", "before": null`
   Those are your "next page" and "previous page" ids. To get the next page, you simply need to call : `GET http://www.reddit.com/r/copypasta/new.json?sort=new&after=t3_hi7vqw`

example using axios:

```
var url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/subreddit/new.json?sort=new"
var response = await axios.get(url);
var after = response.data.data.after;
var copypastas = response.data.data.children.map(x => x.data.selftext);
//copypastas now contains an array of strings being copypatas;
//Change url with url+="&after="+after and repeat the process in a loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I now came up with this:

```
    if (message.channel.type !== 'text') {
    if (message.author.id == client.user.id) return;
    fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/copypasta/new.json?sort=new")
        .then((out) => {
            console.log(out)
            message.reply(`${out.data.data.children[0].data.selftext}`);
        });
        return;
}
```

(I know i could also do `if (message.author.bot) return;` instead of `if (message.author.id == client.user.id) return;` but maybe some bots redirect their DMS in a channel lol)